# How to translate a POST request from Postman to httr:POST in R

Tags: r, post, postman, httr

I want to send a POST request to a facebook.com.api.graphql page and receive a response with events data.
I managed send a POST request to https://www.facebook.com/api/graphql using Postman, and the following keys and values in the body form-data:

**KEY**: **VALUE**

variables: {"pageID":"209194109147358","count":10}

doc_id: 2455863461165494

[image: Postman Screenshot]

Response:

```
{
   "data": {
      "page": {
         "upcoming_events": {
            "edges": [
               {
                  "is_hidden_on_profile_calendar": false,
                  "is_added_to_profile_calendar": false,
                  "node": {
                     "id": "2416302635352362",
                     "startTimestampForDisplay": 1589817600,
                     "time_range": {
                        "start": "2020-05-18T09:00:00-0700"
                     },
                     "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
                     "happensOnSingleDay": false,
                     "childEvents": {
                        "count": 0
                     },
                     "is_event_draft": false,
                     "scheduled_publish_timestamp": 0,
                     "shortTimeLabel": "18. maj - 22. maj",
                     "shortDateLabel": "Man. 18. maj",
                     "suggested_event_context_sentence": {
                        "text": "15 g\u00e6ster"
                     },
                     "event_place": {
                        "__typename": "FreeformPlace",
                        "contextual_name": "Minneapolis Convention Center",
                        "id": "2700549666678444"
                     },
                     "is_canceled": false,
                     "imported_source_name": null,
                     "preassigned_discount_note": null,
                     "name": "DrupalCon Minneapolis",
                     "has_child_events": false,
                     "event_buy_ticket_url": null,
                     "can_viewer_purchase_onsite_tickets": false,
                     "event_viewer_capability": {
                        "is_viewer_admin_no_business_permissions": false,
                        "can_viewer_edit": false,
                        "can_viewer_share": false,
                        "can_viewer_create_repeat_event": false,
                        "canViewerWatch": false
                     },
                     "tickets_type": "ONSITE_TICKET",
                     "canViewerJoin": false,
                     "isPast": false,
                     "connectionStyle": "INTERESTED",
                     "eventID": "2416302635352362",
                     "watchStatus": "UNWATCHED",
                     "canJoin": false,
                     "__typename": "Event"
                  },
                  "cursor": "AQHR-CDTanvfocAXPrNpthiQPd38IxkmIM-X8dsCgvNaS-5GgVPPY1r4B2-G4i64oqoR5V7uQ__B-uZKHzTyd8g5wg"
               }
            ],
            "page_info": {
               "has_next_page": false,
               "end_cursor": "AQHRGvYb3Bp1vBnmF4aHTUuT-FsPomUGSber11DP0LlfpANZ4-hclA6lhKINQ6Av31TbDFGi0YWTQSsiU4Clvggu8A"
            }
         },
         "id": "209194109147358",
         "viewer_profile_permissions": [

         ],
         "admin_info": null
      }
   },
   "extensions": {
      "is_final": true,
      "dtsg_token": null
   }
}
```

I prefer to work with the collected data in R, and therefore would like to send the POST request using httr:POST() instead of Postman.
My attempt so far:

```
url <- "https://www.facebook.com/api/graphql"
params <- list()
params$variables <-  '[{"page_id":"209194109147358", "count":"10"}]'
params$doc_id <- "2455863461165494"
r <- httr::POST(url,body = params, encode = "json")
r
```

Gives me the following response (truncated)

```
Response [https://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser]
  Date: 2020-02-10 14:31
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
  Size: 58.4 kB
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da" id="facebook" class="no_js">
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="referrer" content="default" id="meta_referrer" /><script>window._cstart=+new Date();</script><sc...
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/ym/l/0,cross/h4AfnhSpX0c.css?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz" data-...
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yw/l/0,cross/6oJnmlkR2c_.css?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz" data-...
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yD/l/0,cross/tI6W6dcWoG6.css?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz" data-...
<script src="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/y8/r/6HlB7NWcMJY.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz" data-bootloader-hash="J598A"></script>
<script>requireLazy(["gkx"],function(gkx){gkx.add({"676837":{"result":false,"hash":"AT6VREokr3BzfdNj"},"676940":{"result":false,"hash":"AT...
<script>requireLazy(["Bootloader"],function(Bootloader){Bootloader.setResourceMap({"02wPs":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.n...
<script>requireLazy(["InitialJSLoader"], function(InitialJSLoader) {InitialJSLoader.loadOnDOMContentReady(["SkivO","Gld+B","02wPs","MzCre"...
...
```

The response from in R/httr is not the same as what I get from Postman. Did I set up the parameters incorrectly, or is there some other reason why it works in Postman, but not in R?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try `r <- httr::POST(url,body = params, encode = "form")` that more closely matches what you are doing in postman. Also you passed count as a number in the postman version: `params$variables <-  '[{"page_id":"209194109147358", "count":10}]'`

Comment: A couple of things to try: first it looks like `page_id` should be `pageID`. Secondly, you're getting an unsupported browser page back, so you should have something like `httr::add_headers('User-Agent' = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv =61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0")` in your parameters list to `httr::POST`

Comment: @MrFlick changing count to number didn't have an effect, but changing the encode to "form" led me in the right direction!

Comment: @AllanCameron oh yes thanks for spotting the page_id -> pageID messup!

Comment: @AllanCameron Adding the Mozilla browser as a 'User-Agent' led me to my next error.
To solve this and get a useful response, I had to remove the square brackets from params$variables to end up with '{"page_id":"209194109147358", "count":"10"}'.
Now I just need to make sense of the fromJSON(content(r,"text")) output. But I will leave that for another question :)