# How to write a POST request using httr:POST similar to one used in Postman-app

Tags: r, api, post, postman, httr

I have a similar problem as: [How to translate a POST request from Postman to httr:POST in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152914/how-to-translate-a-post-request-from-postman-to-httrpost-in-r). Below is a view of what I do in Postman:

[Postman_image_post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGMhm.png)

In Postman, I receive a response with the requested data. However when I try to use the same URL and body in R using httr:post, I do not receive any data.

The body I want to parse to httr::post (which is identically to the one used in Postman) is

```
body <- '{ "table": "Fravær løbende år",
  "time": [
    {
      "y1": "2021",
      "m1": "07"
    }
  ],
  "control": [
    "kom_regx",
    "hko_krl",
   "s_ym"
  ],
  "data": [
    "frav_fuldtid",
    "frav_dagsv",
    "frav_dage_pr_fuldtid"
  ],
  "selection": [
    {
      "name": "Udvalgte population",
      "filters": {
        "lif": [
          "10101",
          "10103",
          "10191",
          "10102"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "options": {
    "totals": false,
    "outputFormat": "csv",
    "actions": [],
    "tableName": "Fravær - løbende år",
    "subLimit": 5,
    "modelName": "Fravær",
    "noStkPlus": true,
    "timeIncreasing": false,
    "hideTimeline": 1
  }
}'
```

I have tried different inputs to the httr::POST, none of it working. For example:

```
test <- httr::POST('https://www.krl.dk/sirka/sirkaApi/tableApi', body = body, encode = 'json')
```

When I use verbose() in the function I receive the following:

```
httr::POST('https://www.krl.dk/sirka/sirkaApi/tableApi', body = body, encode = 'json', verbose())

POST /sirka/sirkaApi/tableApi HTTP/1.1
-> Host: www.krl.dk
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.64.1 r-curl/4.3 httr/1.4.2
-> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
-> Cookie: sails.sid=s%3A4B90dPjNtz45qB_YM9O_QpAy4eXuFhvg.ML2mJi%2FSh8J%2FVy9hdukQmmyHjUT9OqUt1bvxLKJUO3o
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Length: 689
-> 
>> { "table": "Fravær løbende år",
>>   "time": [
>>     {
>>       "y1": "2021",
>>       "m1": "07"
>>     }
>>   ],
>>   "control": [
>>     "kom_regx",
>>     "hko_krl",
>>    "s_ym"
>>   ],
>>   "data": [
>>     "frav_fuldtid",
>>     "frav_dagsv",
>>     "frav_dage_pr_fuldtid"
>>   ],
>>   "selection": [
>>     {
>>       "name": "Udvalgte population",
>>       "filters": {
>>         "lif": [
>>           "10101",
>>           "10103",
>>           "10191",
>>           "10102"
>>         ]
>>       }
>>     }
>>   ],
>>   "options": {
>>     "totals": false,
>>     "outputFormat": "csv",
>>     "actions": [],
>>     "tableName": "Fravær - løbende år",
>>     "subLimit": 5,
>>     "modelName": "Fravær",
>>     "noStkPlus": true,
>>     "timeIncreasing": false,
>>     "hideTimeline": 1
>>   }
>> }

<- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<- Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
<- Pragma: no-cache
<- Expires: -1
<- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.krl.dk
<- Connection: close
<- Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
<- Content-Length: 34
<- ETag: W/"22-ccYOpHnkItqR5AChAXo9C/1+jkk"
<- Vary: Accept-Encoding
<- Date: Thu, 04 Nov 2021 11:44:09 GMT
<- 
Response [https://www.krl.dk/sirka/sirkaApi/tableApi]
  Date: 2021-11-04 11:44
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Size: 34 B
```

Can anyone tell me, what I'm doing wrong in httr:POST, when the URL and body is working fine in Postman-app?

/////////
EDIT

Headers from postman: [image: headers_postman]

Comment: Does the site require authentication? What are the 9 headers that POSTMAN has added since httr::POST has probably only got 5 or 6 here? (we can't see them in your POSTMAN screenshot)

Comment: No it does not require authentication. Regarding headers from POSTMAN, I have added a screenshot of the headers at the bottom of the question

Comment: @copenhagen_pds The screenshot apparently says there are nine headers (`Headers (9)`), your screenshot only shows seven.

Comment: @Roman sorry my mistake. I have uploaded a new screenshot with all nine headers visible.

Comment: All right @Copenhagen_PDS, thanks! Now let's break this down: You can extract the received data in `data <- rawToChar(res$content)` (which for me seems like a "IP blocked" message in Danish).1. What is the exact HTTP response that you are expecting? 2. Is there an API specification for this service?

Comment: Yes, the Danish message says that I haven't set the time period in the body (no template for the time period). However, I have right at the top, called "time". 1) I'm expecting a csv file with 8 variables and 38752 lines. That is what a receive in Postman. 2) Yes there is: https://krl.dk/#/apibeta/description. However it is in Danish. There is also a console, where you can try your API call and that works fine as well with the above written body.